# How do I access the result of eval-buffer?

Tags: emacs

Two questions:

1. Where does the result of `eval-buffer` get stored?  How do I access it?
   For example:

   ```
   (+ 2 2)
   ```
2. Functions like `(forward-word)` are executed by `eval-buffer`, but do not move the cursor?  Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `eval-buffer` is usually used for side-effects, rather than return value. For example, in your .emacs file, `eval-buffer` will re-load all our config settings. By default, and when used interactively, it will always return `nil`. If you want to get the return value of code in a buffer, this is the wrong way to do it. `eval-last-sexp`, bound to `C-x C-e`, is one way to do so. Calling it with a prefix, `C-u C-x C-e` will insert the return value into the current buffer.
2. `eval-buffer` preserves the value of point. So functions like `forward-word` will have no visible effect.