# Font Families for Emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts

If I do `M-x customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `default` I can adjust the default face (font) in Emacs.

There are several options, all of them [explained in the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html). Many of these options can be selected from a menu when you select/click on <kbd>Value Menu</kbd>, but not the `Font Family`.

How can I see a list of the fonts that I can use in `Font Family` in Emacs?

Answer (score 23):

Type the following in the `*scratch*` buffer, and press `C-j` at the end of it:

```
(font-family-list)
```

You may need to expand the result to see all of them, by hitting `enter` on the ... at the end.

Comment: If you're having issues doing this with evil-mode, see https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/agdjp1/any_evildoers_or_not_have_better_suggested/ . I had to M-x eval-last-sexp manually.

Comment: In evil-mode, press $ (to move to the end of the expression, which is required in this example), then either C-x C-e (to run eval-last-sexp) for a preview OR, to return the result to the current buffer, press C-u (in Doom Emacs, that's SPC u) C-x C-e. See details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731645/1231693

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Emacs 23.1 or later on the X Window System, the following [`fc-list`](http://ftp.x.org/pub/X11R7.0/doc/html/fc-list.1.html) command can list font families available on your system for Emacs (or any application using fontconfig):

```bsh
$ fc-list : family
```